# MSSQL 2016: How do I Populate an Existing 2+ Billion Row Table with a Unique Primary key?

Tags: sql-server, identity, clustered-primary-key

Is there a way to leverage the identity feature to backfill a primary key for an existing very large table? What I have done in the past is script a new table from the old table adding a new  identifier column (example: column AttributeID int identity(1,1) not null) then writing a t-sql script to populate the table using the rownumber from the source (old table) to manage the inserts in chunks to avoid blowing up the transaction log. Is there a better way to do this?

I realize that even if there is, the next concern will be the needed new space for this added constraint/index + providing more transaction log space.

Any advice regarding a different approach and/or resource management will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9414899/12796048) your question?

Comment: @HandyD, I will try this on a smaller scale. I will update the thread with the results either way.

Comment: May be I'm somewhat off-topic, but for 2 billion + rows, the AttributeID data type should probably be a bigint if I'm correct. you may also set the seed of the identity column to -2,147,483,648, but there will still be a problem when the number of rows reaches 4 billion++.